# preg_replace_callback: Unknown modifier '!'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Pattern:

```
#(?<!\img])(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)|a-z0-9.\-|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#!]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?#i
```

As you can see I got the right modifiers - not like in the other questions. However its still not working giving the error:

```
preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier '!' in [..]
```

Whats the problem? I am out of the ideas. I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have this bit in the middle:

```
([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#!]*
```

You're using `#` as the delimiter, so the regex engine reckons that the `#` in that section is the ending delimiter of the regex. It therefore presumes that the `!` is an attempt at a modifier, and then gets confused when it is an invalid modifier. You need to escape the `#`:

```
([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+\#!]*
```

---

*Edit*

Exactly the same thing happens in the following section:

```
[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#]
```

should be

```
[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+\#]
```

for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: Thats right, I have also tried that - it gives another error: `preg_replace_callback(): Unknown modifier ']'`

Comment: Oh, I must be blind... thank you, works like a charm :)